# current_user and created_at causes TypeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am playing around with ruby trying to implement a basic social network like app.

I have two views where I want to display status updates, the user#show and the home page(where you would add status updates and also visualize your own).

On the home it returns me an error TypeError in Home#index, can't convert nil into an exact number. But if I hard code @user as User.find(1) works fine, it appears to conflict just if @user = current_user (I am using devise).

home controller:

```
    class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = current_user
    @new_status_update = current_user.status_updates.build if user_signed_in?
    @status_updates = @user.status_updates
  end
end
```

The users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource :only => :index

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @status_updates = @user.status_updates
  end

end
```

the loop is the same in the views

Comment: I now noticed that it only happens on calling time_ago_in_words(status_update.created_at)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the problem by wrapping current_user in User.find(current_user)

which probably isn't the best way but at least works..